# Pointwise convergence and convergence in norm for $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis

A question I came across in trying to solve a larger question, and I wanted to understand it.

In $\ell^2$ space of square summable sequences, does pointwise convergence imply convergence in norm? How about the inverse?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for each element $c=(c_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ of $\ell^2$ and each integer $j$, the following inequality holds 
$$
\left\lvert c_j\right\rvert\leqslant \left\lVert c\right\rVert_{\ell^2}
$$
hence if $c^{(n)}$ is a sequence of elements of $\ell^2$ which converges to $c$ in $\ell^2$, then for all $j$, $\left\lvert c_j^{(n)}-c_j\right\rvert\leqslant \left\lVert c^{(n)}-c\right\rVert_{\ell^2}$.

However, it is not true that pointwise convergence implies convergence in $\ell^2$: let $c_k^{(n)}=1$ if $k=n$ and $0$ otherwise.

Comment: Ah. I think I see it now. Thanks!